# Is there something similar to Router class from next/router in nextjs 13?

Tags: forms, validation, next.js, routes, next.js13

I need to check if the user is leaving the page and show him confirm dialog if there have been any changes made. In `NextJs 12` or less, I would use `Router.events`, but in `NextJs 13` they have been removed. Is there some other way to do that, or is there some explanation from next side or an upcoming feature that solves that ?

I currently have it like this, but it only works for refreshing page

```js
export const useWarnIfUnsavedChanges = (unsavedChanges: boolean) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const beforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
      if (unsavedChanges) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = "unsaved changes";
        return "unsaved changes";
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload);
    };
  }, [unsavedChanges]);
};
```